# Duplicate Column name When Inserting Data In Object Views

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, view, object-oriented-database

I Have created an Object view from Existing Relational Table When I am trying To Insert data into the Table using view I am Getting Error. Although I am able to insert data into the Students TABLE in relational way

```
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

My Procedure is following

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
 StudID        NUMBER(6)
 CONSTRAINT Students_StudID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
 Sname         VARCHAR2(15),
 Street        VARCHAR2(20),
 CityName      VARCHAR2(20),
 StateName     VARCHAR2(20),
 PinCode       NUMBER(6)
)
```

This is my relational Table Upon Which I am Creating An Object View

```
CREATE TYPE MyAddress
AS OBJECT
(
Street        VARCHAR2(20),
CityName      VARCHAR2(20),
StateName     VARCHAR2(20),
PinCode       NUMBER(6)
)
```

Another One as

```
CREATE TYPE MyStudent
AS OBJECT
(
  Sname       VARCHAR2(15),
  Saddress    MYAddress
)
```

Now  Object View is Successfully created Using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW StudentOv
(
   StudID,
   StudDEF
)
 AS
  SELECT StudID, MYStudent
      (
         StudID,
         MyAddress
                  (
                    Street,
                    CityName,
                    StateName,
                    PinCode
                  )
      )
FROM Students
```

And when I am Trying to Insert Data into the View I Got the Error Any Help Will be Appreciated. Thanks In Advance

```
INSERT INTO StudentOV
VALUES(1204,
    MYSTUDENT('RAMESH',
            MyAddress(
                     'SHYAMA NAGAR',
                      'SECUNDERABAD',
                       'ANDHRA PRADESH',
                        500601
                       )
                )
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating view, you selected studIdtwice.

Try this... To create view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW StudentOv
(
StudId,
StudDEF
)
AS
SELECT StudId, MYStudent
    (
    StudName,
    MyAddress
          (
          Street,
          CityName,
          StateName,
          PinCode
          )
     )
FROM Students;
```

Then, try to insert the data into the view.